# BeanCreationException on starting up a Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, maven

After building and deploying a spring boot starter project war file, I tried to start the application from the tomcat manager page but keep getting this error in the server side :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/
ibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionF
ctory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.R
LEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELE
SE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEAS
]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEA
E]
       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE

       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6
RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationExcep
tion: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEA
SE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:378) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEAS
E]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.
5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.R
ELEASE]
        ... 50 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.REL
EASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.ja
r:5.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEA
SE]
```

this is my application.properties

```
server.port=9090
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion_stock_mvc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoreconnect=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

and this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.stock.mvc</groupId>
    <artifactId>stock</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Stock-Management-System</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>stock</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I also have an error on my pom.xml about maven.archiver which I could not resolve using other posts

```
org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifest(org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject, org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration)
``
thanks in advance for your help
```

Comment: show as the stacktrace

Comment: @RyanGuamos I updated the description with the stack trace

Comment: Are you using hibernate validators in your project?

Comment: @Reg No hibernate validators are used in my code

Comment: Do you mind sharing some of the entities you are trying to persist?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing but I think your problem is that you need to add the following to your dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Why this?

From your log file.

```
Error activating Bean Validation integration
```